# flex scanner push-back overflow with automata

Tags: flex-lexer, automata

I am having a hard time with this problem.

> "Write a flex code which recognizes a chain with alphabet {0,1}, with at least 5 char's, and to every consecutive 5 char's there will bee at least 3 1's"

I thought I have solved, but I am new using flex, so I am getting this "flex scanner push-back overflow".
here's my code

```
%{
#define ACCEPT  1
#define     DONT    2
%}
delim       [ \t\n\r]
ws          {delim}+
comb01  00111|{comb06}1
comb02  01011|{comb07}1
comb03  01101|{comb08}1
comb04  01110|({comb01}|{comb09})0
comb05  01111|({comb01}|{comb09})1
comb06  10011|{comb10}1
comb07  10101|{comb11}1
comb08  10110|({comb02}|{comb12})0
comb09  10111|({comb02}|{comb12})1
comb10  11001|{comb13}1
comb11  11010|({comb03}|{comb14})0
comb12  11011|({comb03}|{comb14})1
comb13  11100|({comb04}|{comb15})0
comb14  11101|({comb04}|{comb15})1
comb15  11110|({comb05}|{comb16})0
comb16  11111|({comb05}|{comb16})1
accept  {comb01}|{comb02}|{comb03}|{comb04}|{comb05}|{comb06}|{comb07}|{comb08}|{comb09}|{comb10}|{comb11}|{comb12}|{comb13}|{comb14}|{comb15}|{comb16}
string  [^ \t\n\r]+
%%
{ws}        { ;}
{accept}    {return ACCEPT;}
{string}    {return DONT;}
%%
void main () {
    int i;
    while (i = yylex ())
        switch (i) {
            case ACCEPT:
                printf ("%-20s: ACCEPT\n", yytext); 
                break;
            case DONT:
                printf ("%-20s: Reject\n", yytext); 
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: just realized some wrinting mistakes.I wrote it in a hurry

Comment: Are you going to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Flex definitions are macros, and flex implements them that way: when it sees `{defn}` in a pattern, it replaces it with whatever `defn` was defined as (in parentheses, usually, to avoid operator precedence issues). It doesn't expand the macros in the macro definition, so the macro substitution might contain more definition references which in turn need to be substituted.

Since macro substitution is unconditional, it is not possible to use recursive macros, including macros which are indirectly recursive. Which yours are. Flex doesn't check for this condition, unlike the C preprocessor; it just continues substituting in an endless loop until it runs out of space.

(Flex is implemented using itself; it does the macro substitution using [`unput`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-pushing-back-characters-with-unput). `unput` will not resize the input buffer, so "runs out of space" here means that flex's internal flex's input buffer became full of macro substitutions.)

The strategy you are using would work fine as a context-free grammar. But that's not flex. Flex is about regular expressions. The pattern you want to match can be described by a regular expression -- the "grammar" you wrote with flex macros is a regular grammar -- but it is not a regular expression and flex won't make one out of it for you, unfortunately. That's your job.

I don't think it's going to be a very pretty regular expression. In fact, I think it's likely to be enormous. But I didn't try working it out..

There are flex tricks you could use to avoid constructing the regular expression. For example, you could build your state machine out of flex start conditions and then scan one character at a time, where each character scanned does a state transition or throws an error. (Use `more()` if you want to return the entire string scanned at the end.)